# Disable Azure service bus printing logs in cloud watch

Tags: java, azure, aws-lambda

I was getting  following error message in aws lambda logs :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

so i added maven depdenecies as  :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
```

But on adding slfj4j dependencies unwated logs from azure service bus are also getting printed now eg.

```
[ReactorThread1288184d-400a-4928-b174-b819c8bd9ee1] INFO com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.MessagingFactory - starting reactor instance.
```

my log4j.xml looks like this  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2">
    <Appenders>
        <Lambda name="Lambda">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %X{AWSRequestId} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Lambda>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Lambda" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

How can i disable these logs getting printed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related with the logging dependencies of your project.

On one hand, you have AWS Lambda over Log4j2, which uses Log4j2 for logging. On the other hand you have Azure Service Bus, which uses the SLF4J API facade for logging. You need to configure your system to support both logging approaches.

First of all, you need the following dependencies in your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ....
</dependencies>
```

The first dependency allows you to emit log traces to AWS Lambda.

The last one is the Log4j2 SLF4J java bridge, necessary for Azure Service Bus logging.

Please, also remove the dependency `slf4j-simple` associated with the group `org.slf4j`, it will be no necessary.

With this dependencies in place, please, include the following line:

```xml
<Logger name="com.microsoft.azure.servicebus" level="OFF"/>
```

In your XML configuration file (by convention, it is better to name your Log4j2 configuration file like `log4j2.xml` instead of `log4j.xml`, more appropriate for the old Log4j library version).

Your `log4j2.xml` should looks something like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.log4j2">
    <Appenders>
        <Lambda name="Lambda">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %X{AWSRequestId} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Lambda>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.microsoft.azure.servicebus" level="OFF"/>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Lambda" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: thanks .i tried the appraoch .service bus logs were getting printed still . then i removed my log4j.xml from project .then i noticed none of my lambda logs were getting printed but  service bus logs were still prinitng even though i did not had any log4j.xml

Comment: Please, let me check it out how the logs of service bus are actually being generated.

Comment: this is from maven depdency tree [INFO] +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.qpid:proton-j:jar:0.33.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:qpid-proton-j-extensions:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.28:compile

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my answer with further information. Please, can you try?

Comment: I forgot to mention: please, you can also remove the dependencies associated with the group ```org.slf4j``` from the ```pom.xml``` file, they are no longer required as they are provided as transitive dependencies of the ```log4j-slf4j18-impl``` artifact and the Azure Service Bus library.

Comment: sure will try this solution and update you if it works .

Comment: Thank you @divyanayanawasthi. Please, let me know if I can be of any help.

Comment: @divyanayanawasthi Could you give it a try? Did it worked?

Comment: i tried the apporach again mentioned by you but was getting StaticLoggerBinding.class error .so i added slf4j-simple maven depepdency .looks like LOGGER to off logs from service bus is not working .

Comment: @divyanayanawasthi Thank you for your feedback.I updated my answer. Sorry, I indicated you ```log4j-slf4j18-impl``` as the SLF4J binding for Log4j2, but it should be ```log4j-slf4j-impl``` instead, because we are using SLF4J 1.7.See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/. Please, can you try it again? I am quite sure It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. will mark your answer as the solution

Comment: You are welcome @divyanayanawasthi. Nice!! I am glad to hear that the answer was helpful. Thank you.

Comment: one small thing we only need <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.2</version>
  </dependency> depdedency along with aws-lambda-java-log4j2 and logger level off in log4j.xml for service bus logs. if possible please update your answer .

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not an error. The message means that there is no logger implementation present in the classpath and hence it is defaulting to NOP (No-operation) log. And as SLF4J is an abstraction of different logging frameworks, you also need to include specific logging framework in your classpath apart from only having SLF4J. Since you are trying to use Lambda appender, you need to add [aws-lambda-java-log4j2](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-log4j2) to your classpath. This will bring in required SLF4J dependencies also.

**Latest version as of May 05, 2020:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Shyam thanks for responding .i have log4j2 depdendency . let me check with 1.2.0 version . .its just it increases cold start for aws lambda .but when i add slf4j libraries .cold start time of aws lambda decreases but azure service bus logs are also getting printed in the cloud watch logs .how  can i modify my log4j config to stop these info logs getting printed .i dont want to change logging level .

Comment: If you have log4j2 dependency, then you should not add SLF4J dependency separately. log4j2 will bring in required dependencies.

Comment: i updated the version and tried .getting same error . As already mentioned i already had the library for aws-log4j in my pom .